# How to Retrieve outlook property using emailid?

Tags: c#, outlook

I want to retrieve country, department, display name property from outlook.
Manually we are done using ctrl+k then right click outlook property.

If lots of records, then its time consuming process.

I have one mail id like `var email="Something@domain.com"`

Using

```
var a=outlook.Application.CreateReciepent("Email@hjg.com");
a.resolve();
var name=a.name;
```

able to fetch display name.

how to retrieve corresponding email id --country, department.

Please help me.

Comment: Those properties are usually stored in active directory, so instead of trying to find them via outlook, it would be easier to search the active directory

Comment: i don't know, please help me

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to add System.DirectoryServices in the reference and userName in the code below is the NT Id (without domain). If you want to look for more properties you will need to search online for the exact string.

DirectorySearcher search = new DirectorySearcher();

```
    // specify the search filter
    search.Filter = "(&(objectClass=user)(anr=" + userName + "))";

    // specify which property values to return in the search
    search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("displayName");   // display name
    search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("co");          // country name
    search.PropertiesToLoad.Add("department");        // department

    // perform the search
    SearchResult result = search.FindOne();
```

Comment: how to read result data. in quick watch able to view data but not in outside.

Comment: see the type of result.Properties, you can do something like: result.Properties["displayName"][0]

Comment: This will only work if the computer is on the domain the mailbox is located, If it will not work for a computer not on a domain or for an Outlook profile accessing a mailbox not hosted by the machine's domain.